# How to install a git project on a commercial hosted php web setup

Tags: php, paypal

I am considering using the following paypal sdk which is available on github:
https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-PHP-SDK

The paypal help at:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/setup-sdk/

says to install using composer like this:
composer require paypal/paypal-checkout-sdk 1.0.1

However I don't have command line access on my webhosting service so I presume I won't be able to do that?

What are my options?

Presumably I could just manually ftp the required file up to my web host?

Or do I just have to work without the sdk?

My goal is to allow people to buy products via paypal on my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install it in a local environment, do your development and test that it works, then FTP all the files over